# CasperJS don't make my AJAX request

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I've a bug with CasperJS. I'm trying to click on a link where there is an AJAX request on onclick. The AJAX request is never made.

Here is my index.php page :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>AJAX test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js>
    </script>
    <script>
    function test(id){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    'id': id
                },
                url: 'test.php',
                async: false
        });
        alert('OK');
        return true;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a onclick="return test(1)" href="http://www.google.fr">www.google.fr</a>
</body>
</html>
```

My test.php page :

```
<?php 

print_r($_POST['id']);
mail('mymail', 'Test AJAX', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].' : '.$_POST['id']);

?>
```

And my CasperJS script :

```
var utils = require('utils');
var casper = require('casper').create({
verbose: true,
logLevel: "debug"
});

casper.start('http://www.example.com/index.php');

casper.thenEvaluate(function(term) {}, 'CasperJS');

casper.then(function() {
    this.click('a');
});

casper.then(function() {
    console.log('clicked ok, new location is ' + this.getCurrentUrl());
});

casper.run();
```

The "alert" message is well launched, but not the AJAX request. Do you know why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OKay, I found the answer. The problem was because I was using a proxy which need an authentification, and the AJAX request wasn't sending the user and password required.

I directly configure the proxy to allow all connection from my IP without authentification, and it works.